# Is it safe to still use ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

Ben Copsey has abandoned ASIHTTPRequest. [It has been announced almost two months ago](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) but I just realized it.

I'm in the middle of a project using it. It wouldn't be an huge problem for me to replace it with something else at this stage (everyone is talking about AFNetworking right now), but:

1. If I can avoid replacing it it's better. I'd rather spend that time working on other things
2. I'd like to support iOS < 4, but AFNetworking and LRResty are 4> only
3. I also have a few other apps that heavily depend on it

I'm pretty sure other folks are in my situation. So my question is: is it safe to continue using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it works for you already, there is no point replacing it. Ben has only stopped development of it himself, that doesn't mean others are not free to continue developing it.

It just means that it won't get updated.

On the blog post he has provided other options that you can use.

Comment: It looks like it does still get updated (though perhaps not as frequently as before) - there have been commits merged since Ben's announcement, see https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/commits/master

Answer (score 0):

I would continue using it. He probably quit working on it because it had all the functionality possible and was complete for all time (jk).  Seriously though, it's a great library and your only fear would maybe be something that might break in a new version of iOS, but I guarantee someone will develop a fix for something like that.