# ASIHTTPRequest : Adding Header which should send with every request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I am working in a iPhone project that uses restful web services. I need to send some tracking code or version number with every request sending from iPhone side. I am thinking of adding a header value into every request, by modifying a ASIHTTPRequest class.

1. Is there any method that ASIHTTPRequest providing to do this (without modifying framework files)?
2. If I need to modify ASIHTTPRequest class, what is the best place to modify it? (like buildRequestHeaders.. )

Thanks.

Comment: Either change in the source if it is open or subclass it.

Comment: I already have some coding stuff and i want to add this header without change it from every location.

Comment: Then it's better to  change the source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be you can write a  new class such as MyASIHttprequest and override the method requestwithURL

```
+ (MyASIHTTPrequest *) requestWithURL:url{
    MyASIHTTPrequest *request;
    if (request = [super requestWithUrl:url]){
        [request addRequestHeader:@""  value:@""];
    }
    return request;
}
```

or you can write a method to add the header but maybe every time you new a asihttprequest, you should call this method to add header;

Answer (score 4):

You can add headers by following method

```
ASIFormDataRequest *currentRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[currentRequest addRequestHeader:@""  value:@""];

e.g.[currentRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type"  value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: will it work for audio file by adding audio/wav as content type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting by adding in ASIHTTPRequest and it is not embedded into your app yet then I recommend that you stop and switch to something else.

The creator of ASIHTTPRequest has discontinued development on the framework and even recommends in his blog post "Honestly, I think now is the time to start looking elsewhere." -[Blog post](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;)

Also this was addressed in this question as well: [Is it safe to still use ASIHTTPRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109203/is-it-safe-to-still-use-asihttprequest)

I would personally recommend that you use NSURLConnection and send the data through the POST method.