# ASIHTTP Request & Classes

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone application development and working on a web service based application.

I am using NSXML parser in this application and all is working finr, I am able to get the data from server.

But my friend told me that I should include ASIHTTP Classes in this project that is mandatory, but I wonder as I have not used any usch classes as of now and still i am able to fetch the data successfully.

Can any body please explain me what is the purpose of ASIHTTP classes and if i don't use it then would that be a right approach?

I will also need to do Lazy loading in my project so will that  be possible without ASIHTTP Classes?

Please help me to clear my doubts.

Thanks in advance.
iPhone Developer

Comment: Whilst there may be benefits switching to ASIHTTPRequest, there is no longer any active development on this wrapper since September 2011, for your reference. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109203/is-it-safe-to-still-use-asihttprequest

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain any information you're looking for from here, [ASIHTTPRequest - How To Use](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Alternatively, you can use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Both routes you can use `Asynchronous` request to perform lazy loading.